# dbctrlgrid delete and populate entries at runtime

Tags: delphi, runtime, parent, delphi-2009

I want to load the content of of dbctrlgrid at runtime (from database). So I encountered several challenges:

1. How to detect if the dbctrlgrid is empty and/or how to clear it.
2. How to put Tlabel and Tdbtext on the panel. The main problem seems to be to find the right parent. dbctrlgrid doesn't work. There is an object called Tdbctrlpanel which should work, but I don't know how to access it. I could not find it in properties or methods of Tdbctrlgrid.

Any code snipplet is welcome

Comment: You should always **add** the generic [tag:delphi] tag to your delphi related questions to have the correct syntax highlighter and more attention on your question.

Comment: A TDBCtrlGrid is meant to be designed (laid out) in the Form Designer. Simply drop `TLabel` and `TDBText` controls where you want them, and connect them to the DataSource and DataField using the Object Inspector like you would any other data aware control. To clear it, you simply set the dataset's `Active` property to false, or delete all of the data in the dataset.. You tell if it's empty by checking the dataset's `IsEmpty` property. You add entries by adding data to the dataset, and the DBCtrlGrid will automatically add another panel and controls to display it.

Comment: May be I got it wrong, but I understood that the TDBCtrlGrid has to be adapted to the changing table structure. Similar to a TDBGrid that adapts to the given columns (as long as you don't design any columns). Perhaps I am thinking too complicated?

Comment: You are both right and wrong:

Comment: My datatable has many fields e.g. more than 30 and I present in the dbctrlgrid not more than 15. I will allow the user to select the fields at runtime. So they have to remove an existing dbtext or to change the fieldname property. When I want to allow to change the position, it must be removed and then new inserted.

Comment: DbCtrlgrid doesn't show all fields in a datatable. You can select a few. So what I want is not to check if the database contains no data, it contains allways data.

Comment: If I were you I would place **all** controls on that grid. Depending on what has to be shown or not I would simply change the visible property and rearrange the remaining controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add controls to a `TDBCtrlGrid` you have to set the controls parent to the `Panel` property of the `TDBCtrlGrid`. The problem is that this property is protected. There are several ways to overcome this limitation. One is shown at Delphi About: [Accessing protected members of a component](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/l/aa082603a.htm) 
This is a common technique known to Delphi programmers as the 'protected hack'.

Comment: It works also with
parent:=TdbCtrlPanel(DBCtrlGrid1.Controls[0]);

Answer (score 1):

To answer 1)

You don't query the TDBCtrlGrid, you query the underlying dataset; if it `.IsEmpty` the grid is empty.

When people start using data aware (grid) components they have the tendency to see that as the 'data container' that you can query and modify, but that is not the case. See it as a view on your underlying data with some built-in editors that modify that data. Then the 'same rules' apply to you as to these editors: update the underlying dataset.